# Parsing comment in Rascal

Tags: comments, rascal

I have a very basic question about parsing a fragment that contains comment.
First we import my favorite language, Pico:

```
import lang::pico::\syntax::Main;
```

Then we execute the following:

```
 parse(#Id,"a");
```

gives, as expected:

```
 Id: (Id) `a`
```

However,

```
parse(#Id,"a\n%% some comment\n");
```

gives a parse error.

What do I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems.

1. `Id` is a lexical, meaning layout (comments) are never there
2. Layout is only inserted between elements in a production and the `Id` lexical has only a character class, so no place to insert layout.
3. Even if Id was a syntax non terminal with multiple elements, it would parse comments between them not before or after.

For more on the difference between `syntax`, `lexical`, and `layout` see: [Rascal Syntax Definitions](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Declarations/SyntaxDefinition/SyntaxDefinition.html).

If you want to parse comments around a non terminal, we have the `start` modified for the non terminal. Normally, layout is only inserted between elements in the production, with start it is also inserted before and after it.

Example take this grammer:

```
layout L = [\t\ ]* !>> [\t\ ];
lexical AB = "A" "B"+;
syntax CD = "C" "D"+;
start syntax EF = "E" "F"+;
```

this will be transformed into this grammar:

```
AB   = "A" "B"+;
CD'  = "C" L "D"+;
EF'  = L "E" L "F"+ L;
"B"+ = "B"+ "B" | "B";
"D"+ = "D"+ L "D" | "D";
"F"+ = "F"+ L "F" | "F";
```

So, in particular if you'd want to parse a string with layout around it, you could write this:

```
lexical Id = [a-z]+;
start syntax P = Id i;
layout L = [\ \n\t]*;

parse(#start[P], "\naap\n").top // parses and returns the P node
parse(#start[P], "\naap\n").top.i // parses and returns the Id node
parse(P, "\naap"); // parse error at 0 because start wrapper is not around P
```